ReactPixi Gradient color
I want to make an gradient background object within React Pixi, but I'm unable to.
This attempt, just draws white background, not the gradient. Do you know any tips/tricks how to do this, or even the knowledge if this is possible.
  function gradient(from, to) {
    const c = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    const grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 100, 100);
    grd.addColorStop(0, from);
    grd.addColorStop(1, to);
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
    return new PIXI.Texture.from(c);
  }

  const draw = React.useCallback((g) => {
    g.clear()
    g.beginTextureFill(gradient('red', 'blue'))
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
    g.endFill()
  }, []);

  return <Graphics draw={draw} />


Look here
